# React - JSON, Conditional

Tags: json, reactjs, if-statement

I have a JSON file, i wanted to know how do I go about calling it into react and from there making images show based on the value in the JSON being true or false.

Example, if the value is true display image, if false hide image.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

sample.json

```
{
  "val": false
}
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import jsonData from "./sample.json";

export default function BrowsePage() {
  return <div>{jsonData.val && <div>Hi</div>}</div>;
}
```